# Exact matches with match query on analyzed field not showing on top

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a data set like below

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Duvvuri ram gopal reddy"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "ram gopal reddy"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "reddy ram gopal"
            }
         }
      ]
```

When i try to perform a match query with value as `ram gopal reddy` exact matched record is not showing on top.
Query:

```
GET demotest/_search
{
    "explain": true, 
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "ram gopal reddy"
        }
    }
}
```

Result after execution of above query:

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.8630463,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Duvvuri ram gopal reddy"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.7594807,
            "_source": {
               "name": "ram gopal reddy"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "demotest",
            "_type": "demotest",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.7594807,
            "_source": {
               "name": "reddy ram gopal"
            }
         }
      ]
```

How to get exact matched record on top in search results. Also, I posted my complete test [here](https://gist.github.com/shashankgutha/0b75774d273091590dd0765ee63276af) and I want case insensitive search and not phrase search. Thanks

Comment: What Elasticsearch version is this?

Comment: I am using elastic 5.1.2 version

Comment: Strange, even if the 3 words "reddy ram gopal" are in all documents (I mean  with a low score according TF/IDF), shorter field should have a best score than long field (according TF/IDF doc here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html), can you post ``_explain`` details please?

Comment: please find explain details [here](https://gist.github.com/shashankgutha/8757565a6be5f2c57d64e6ff189c2358)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a bool query with multiple should clauses. One would be set with a phrase query and the other one as a match query.

I wrote a full (but complex example) here: https://gist.github.com/dadoonet/5179ee72ecbf08f12f53d4bda1b76bab

Should give something like:

```
GET oss/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": {
              "query" : "ram gopal reddy",
              "boost": 8.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "ram gopal reddy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not get desired result with above answer.
I posted my complete test [here](https://gist.github.com/shashankgutha/0b75774d273091590dd0765ee63276af)
and I want case insensitive search and not phrase search.